# How to filter out other selected options using contains or in function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a questionnaire designed like this:

```
What is(are) your favorite food? 
1: Apple
2: Banana
3: Pear
4: Other ____

The result is like this: 
ID      Options chosen
1        Apple, Banana
2        Apple
3        Apple, Banana, Pear, Orange
4        Orange
```

So the count should be like this

```
Apple: 3
Banana: 2
Pear: 1
Other: 2
```

I tried using pandas, but still couldn't figure out the way to create the table:

```
options = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear']
df['options'].isin(options)
```

But the result turns out to be all False, let alone the count for Other  option.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `df.options = df.options.str.split(', ')`, `df = df.explode('options').reset_index(drop=True)` and then `df.options.value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select()` in combination with explode to get get the count of the items to specify and put those that aren't in the given list in the "other" category

```
df['Options chosen'] = df['Options chosen'].apply(lambda x : x.split(', '))
df = df.explode('Options chosen')
condition_list = [df['Options chosen'].isin(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear'])]
choice_list = [df['Options chosen']]
df['Options chosen'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, 'Other')
df = df.groupby('Options chosen').count().reset_index()
df
```